# OneToOne Mapping with cascade = CascadeType.DETACH

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
       class Person { 
        @Id
        private  Long id;

        @Column(name = "NAME");
        private String name;

        @OneToOne(mappedBy="person", cascade = CaseCadeType.DETACH)
        private SocialId socialId;

    }



     class SocialId {
        @Id
        private  Long id;
        @Column(name = "NAME");
        private String name;

        @Column(name ="PERSON_ID")
        private Long personId;

        @OneToOne(cascade = CaseCadeType.DETACH)
        @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private Person person;
    }

   @Transactional
   public void customSave(Person person) {
     SocailId socialId = person.getSocialId();
     // Person Save
     personrepo.save(person);
     socialId.setPersonId(person.getId());     
     // SocailId Save
     socialIdRepo.save(socialId);    
   }
```

I have above case, Will it work. Please don't consider anything, just for the trail purposeI have created two entity.

My question is 
1. I have declared a @Transactional for customSave what will happen after this.

2. If I have to make this to work what adjustment I need to make.
3. P.S: I fixed the issue. I would like to know what are all things wrong in the above declarations right. If It is correct, how and why.

Comment: is there any specific reason to use insertable = false, updatable = false and cascade = CaseCadeType.DETACH ?

Comment: You don't need to have Long personId property in SocialId class since you have Person mapped to SocialId but it would be a column in Person table as FK.

Comment: @Uzair : 1) Yes using DETACH is some thing, I should be able to insert Person and SocialId without the existence of the it's related entity., reason to make it insertable = false, updatable = false is to restrict the column creation for the personId 2) I used PERSON_ID, to be column in socialId, just to make it independent column. Just try things around. Doesn't have any business cases. But just trying this around.

Comment: you don't need it, you can achieve the same with orphanRemoval=false and in script add on delete null while defining foreign key. You can add SocialId without having Person, in that case persion_id would set to null, you can attach person_id later

Comment: @Uzair:  Okay. is it possible to save Person and Social under a same transactional method like I mentioned above Transactional
   public void customSave(Person person) {
     SocailId socialId = person.getSocialId();
     // Person Save
     personrepo.save(person);
     socialId.setPersonId(person.getId());     
     // SocailId Save
     socialIdRepo.save(socialId);    
   }

Comment: Yes, Transaction is supposed to handle multiple interactions to DataBase within the transaction boundary. If it helped, don't forget to accept the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any use of `cascade = CaseCadeType.DETACH` instead you can use `cascade = CaseCadeType.ALL` and you can remove `insertable = false, updatable = false`, instead `orphanRemoval = false` and by default it is false.

So can have Person without having SocialId, in that case your socialId will set to null and you can attach it later (I believe you want social_id as FK in Person rather than person_id in SocialId entity/table)

So your modified code will be as below

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "PERSON")
 class Person { 

    @Id
    private  Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME");
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = false, mappedBy = "person")
    private SocialId socialId;


}



 @Entity
 @Table(name = "SOCIAL_ID")
 class SocialId {



        @Id
        private  Long id;
        @Column(name = "NAME");
        private String name;


       @OneToOne
       @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_PERSON_ID"))
       private Person person;
}
```

Your DaoMethod, you don't have to save both separately since they are mapped to each other. If you save set social id to Person and saves Person, socialid will automatically be saved by JPA.

```
 @Transactional
   public void customSave(Person person) {
     SocailId socialId = person.getSocialId();
     // Person Save
     personrepo.save(person);
     socialId.setPersonId(person.getId());     
     // SocailId Save
     socialIdRepo.save(socialId);    
   }
```